# ANOVA: single or combined statements

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, pca, mean, factor-analysis

I want to test a hypothesis that states that country of origin significantly influences the consumers' price perception of electronics 'Made in Country X'.

In my data, i have four questions measuring this price perception. They are

1. How high would you estimate the price of this Country X laptop given the image above?
2. How high would you estimate the price of this National laptop given the image above?
3. What is the max. amount you would be willing to pay for this Country X laptop?
4. What is the max. amount you would be willing to pay for this National laptop?

Can I conduct a one-way ANOVA to compare the means btw. the two first questions and then another one-way ANOVA to compare the means btw. the 3. and 4. question in order to answer my hypothesis?

Or does it make more sense to combine these 4 questions into one factor using factor analysis? How would I compute this in Excel?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the same person answers to the 4 questions, then it's a repeated measurements settings we are studying to compare the answers to the 4 questions. (I hope I understood correctly what you wish to do.)

If the Normality assumption can be assumed, then you could do an ANOVA for repeated measures. If Normality can not be assumed, you can do a Friedman test.

Regarding Factor Analysis, I don't see how would it be useful here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! How can I test the normality distribution? I am not sure which variables I have to use for the histogram in excel in order to check it. Do i compute a histogram for each of the four questions? Is repeated ANOVA the same as Two Way ANOVA with repetition?

Comment: And would I do two repeated ANOVAs (question 1 vs question 2) and then another one (question 3 vs question 4) or can I compute a single ANOVA for all four to check if there are significant differences in outcomes?

Comment: If the sample is large enough (near 100 or more answers to each question) you can do a Q-Q plot and look at the skewness and kurtosis of each of the 4 questions. I don't know how to make Q-Q plots in excel, but I know it's possible to get the skewness and kurtosis. If both skewness and kurtosis are in $[-2; 2]$ the deviation from the normality is not too big. Regarding the ANOVA for repeated measures, I suggest that you only do one. You can compute later paired t-tests between the questions you want. The two way ANOVA with repetition may be a different thing in excel, I can't tell for sure.